# How to create a new Dictionary<,> from an IReadOnlyDictionary<,>?

Tags: c#, dictionary

.NET 4.5 introduces the handy `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface. A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` *is-an* `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, so I can just pass the former wherevert the latter is required.

I'm not sure about the opposite way, though: *How do I create a new `Dictionary<,>` based on an existing `IReadOnlyDictionary<,>`?*

- `Dictionary<,>` has several constructors that take an `IDictionary<,>` -- but none that take an `IReadOnlyDictionary<,>`.
- `IReadOnlyDictionary<,>` has an extension method `ToDictionary<,>()`. However, that's inherited from `IEnumerable<>`. So to use it, I have to pass two utterly redundant delegates like this: `readOnlyDict.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)`. Ugly!
- Of course, I can always create a new `Dictionary<,>`, iterate over the original pairs and copy them over.

It seems to me that there should be a trivial way to create a new `Dictionary<,>` based on an existing `IReadOnlyDictionary<,>`. Am I missing something?

**Edit:** Some clarification. I'm not looking for some magic way of treating an `IReadOnlyDictionary<,>` as a `Dictionary<,>`. I want to create a new `Dictionary<,>` that copies its initial values from an `IReadOnlyDictionary<,>`. This question is a long-winded way of asking:

*`Dictionary<,>` has a convenience constructor to copy the initial values from an `IDictionary<,>`. How come it doesn't have one taking an `IReadOnlyDictionary<,>` and what's the most idiomatic way of achieving the same result?*

Answer (score 22):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is able to implement `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, because any code that takes the latter is promising not the modify the dictionary, which is a subset of the functionality the former provides.

But consider the other direction. You start with an `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, and you try to turn it into a regular `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Now, you've taken something that had previously been promised to not be modified, and turned it into something that may be modified.

Clearly, that just won't do.

Furthermore, you can't just assume that the read-only implementation would throw an exception or something when modified (e.g. run-time safety even though not compile-time safety) because, as you know, you can always get the read-only interface from a mutable implementation.

So to be safe, you have two options:

1. Just copy the entire dictionary contents into a new object.
2. Wrap the read-only object in an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implementation that *does* throw an exception if you try to modify it.

Note that the latter does not actually give you what you are specifically asking for. It's close, but it's not an actual instance of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

In terms of copying, you have many choices. Personally, I think `ToDictionary()` is itself just fine. But if you really don't like the verbosity, you can wrap it in an extension method:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>(
    this IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
{
    return dict.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```

**Addendum:**
It occurs to me that I should probably clarify: the above all assumes you are trying to convert an *arbitrary* instance of `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Obviously, if you know or at least suspect that your `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` object is in fact an instance of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, you can cast or attempt to cast (respectively) directly to `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: Well there could be static methods with a different names, so resolution wouldn't be an issue. Like: Dictionary.CreateFromReadOnly and Dictionary.CreateFrom

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `IReadOnlyDictionary<>` was added later, and existing classes (such as `Dictionary<>`) were not retrofitted to support it with *new* methods, for backward compatibility reasons. [citation needed], though.

For what it's worth, [Microsoft's reference implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com) of `Dictionary`'s constructor is essentially

```
Dictionary(IDictionary dictionary)
: this(dictionary.Count) {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> pair in dictionary) {
            Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
}
```

And `Enumerable` is essentially

```
Dictionary<> ToDictionary<>(this IEnumerable<> source, Func<> keySelector, Func<> elementSelector) 
{
    Dictionary<> d = new Dictionary<>();
    foreach (TSource element in source) 
    d.Add(keySelector(element), elementSelector(element));
    return d;
}
```

So the difference seems to be mainly the calls to the selector delegates.

So an extension method copying the constructor's code but taking a `IReadOnlyDictionary<>`, more or less as @Steve did, seems slightly simpler and slightly more efficient...

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = readOnlyDictionary
                .Select(dict => dict).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The oft-cited answer for any "why doesn't C# have this feature" is that it takes time to design, implement, document, test, etc., especially when source and binary compatibility with existing code must be taken into account.

Intuitively, any `IDictionary<,>` would also be a `IReadOnlyDictionary<,>` (the latter is a subset of the former's interface), and perhaps if `IReadOnlyDictionary<,>` had existed from the start it would be set up that way (with the relevant constructor taking `IReadOnlyDictionary<,>` as its argument, and automatically accepting an `IDictionary<,>` due to inheritance), but as things stand `IDictionary<,>` and `IReadOnlyDictionary<,>` are unrelated interfaces that happen to include the same functions. I can only assume the reason they're unrelated is to avoid breaking existing user code that does an explicit interface implementation of `IDictionary<,>`.

As such, a new constructor taking a `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` would either be a new unrelated function that happens to contain identical-looking code to the existing constructor taking a `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, or one or other constructor would need to use a wrapper.

I can only assume that this was not considered more important than other possible features in the pipeline...

... and the fact that when I encountered the same problem, it was quite hard to find the existing question (and even then it had been around for 1.5 years without an answer to the question being asked), suggests that they were right to prioritise other more important features.

In my own case, I had a class that derives from `Dictionary<MyEnum,double>` (in order to have a dictionary that also implements an interface by accessing specific keys), and wanted to write a constructor like:

```
public MyDictionary(IReadOnlyDictionary<MyEnum, double> source) : base(source)
{ }
```

Instead, after trying to see in anyone else had a similar problem (and finding this question) I wrote something similar to the following:

```
public MyDictionary(IReadOnlyDictionary<MyEnum, double> source)
{
  foreach (var pair in source)
    base.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

In cases where we're directly creating a `Dictionary<,>`, there are at least two perfectly readable options - a loop similar to the above, or the `ToDictionary` extension function that the original question rejected solely for being "ugly" (I rejected it because it would mean copying the dictionary twice - once in the `ToDictionary` call, and once in the base class constructor).

I'd expect the "missing" constructor on `Dictionary<,>` to be equally trivial in implementation, but they'd also need to deal with all the other associated palaver that accompanies any new feature. `Dictionary<,>` and `IDictionary<,>` are VERY widely used in all sorts of interesting ways, making the potential for breaking stuff even with the simplest and most innocuous of changes even greater.

**Edit:** Thinking further... if the "missing" constructor were to be implemented, it would make it ambiguous which constructor should be called for a class which implements **both** interfaces `IDictionary<,>` and `IReadOnlyDictionary<,>`. The prime example being the Dictionary class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be simpler than this. (you need to define TKey and TValue)

```
var NewDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(ReadOnlyDictionary.AsEnumerable());
```